# Splitting a line(Fixed-size chunks) and identifying adjacent word in python

Tags: python, split

Would like to split below line

```
*SECTION_TSHELL
$#   secid    elform      shrf       nip     propt   qr/irid     icomp    tshear
         1         2       0.0         5         0       0.0
*MAT_ELASTIC
$#     mid        ro         e        pr        da        db  not used
     Steel  8000.0002.0000e+11  0.300000       0.0       0.0       0.0
```

The format of the file is such that every pid, secid etc. takes 10 spaces again & again.
Example in above

Step 1: The Bold letters takes 10 (*$#     mid*) spaces when you select. with this would like to split a line using specific number of spaces.
Step 2: After splitting, the adjacent value need to be identified.

```
import os

ModelPath = 'D:\pyLearning\Read_all_files'

k_files = os.listdir(ModelPath)

if k_files:

    include_file = "_K3_Controls.k"

    include_file_path = os.path.join(ModelPath, include_file)

    with open(include_file_path, 'r') as include_kfile:
        parts = include_kfile.read()
        print("TestEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEnd")

        for lines in parts:
            if not lines.startswith('$#'):
                # parts = lines.split()
                length = 10
                splits = [parts[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(parts), length)]
                # print("Worked", splits)
                try:
                    i = splits.index("Steel")
                    next_word = splits[i + 1]
                    print(f"Steel = {next_word}")
                except(ValueError, IndexError):
                    pass

print("finished")
```

Expecting the output somewhat like this
Worked ['Steel', '8000.000', '2.0000e+11', '  0.300000']

and at the end

Steel = 8000.000

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Unfortunately, splliting is not happening as expected and adjacent word is not detecting.

Comment: `for line in parts` is iterating over characters, not lines. You want `parts = include_kfile.readlines()` to make a list of lines.

Comment: Tried with readlines but it lists based on spaces but in next step identifying adjacent word will be difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to split the file into lines. You could just use `for lines in include_kfile:`

When you create `splits`, you should be slicing `lines`, not `parts`:

```
splits = [lines[i:i + length] for i in range(0, len(lines), length)]
```

You're not accounting the for leading spaces in each item in `splits` when you search for `Steel`. You could strip them off when you're splitting.

```
splits = [lines[i:i + length].strip() for i in range(0, len(lines), length)]
```

Put together:

```
with open(include_file_path, 'r') as include_kfile:
    for lines in include_kfile:
        if not lines.startswith('$#'):
            # parts = lines.split()
            length = 10
            splits = [lines[i:i + length].strip() for i in range(0, len(lines), length)]
            #print("Worked", splits)
            try:
                i = splits.index("Steel")
                next_word = splits[i + 1]
                print(f"Steel = {next_word}")
            except(ValueError, IndexError):
                pass
```

Comment: Thank you very much for you explanation and quick response. It worked flawlessly :)

Answer (score 0):

> *"Splitting a line(Fixed-size chunks) and identifying adjacent word in python ..."*

Start by qualifying the data.

There appears to be a group heading atop a grid of data; with column headers.

So, divide the data into lines; we'll presume there are only three lines, per group.
Although, I imagine the row-data could plausibly continue, indefinitely.

Traverse the lines, advancing the iteration once for each *sub-set* of values; or row.
And, for each of these values, divide the content; for every *10* characters.

As a final step, *[zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)* these two *lists*, to correlate the datum, with the column header.

Here is an example, where *s* is the text.

```py
import re, itertools as i
data = {}
for line in (it := iter(s.splitlines())):
    headers = [x.group().strip() for x in re.finditer('.{10}', next(it))]
    values = [x.group().strip() for x in re.finditer('.{10}', next(it))]
    data.update({line: dict(i.zip_longest(headers, values))})
```

Optionally, you may want to eliminate the *'*'*, and *'#$'*, characters.

```py
for line in (it := iter(s.splitlines())):
    headers = [x.group().strip() for x in re.finditer('.{10}', next(it))]
    headers[0] = headers[0][2:].strip()
    values = [x.group().strip() for x in re.finditer('.{10}', next(it))]
    data.update({line[1:]: dict(i.zip_longest(headers, values))})
```

Output

```
{'SECTION_TSHELL': {'secid': '1', 'elform': '2', 'shrf': '0.0', 'nip': '5', 'propt': '0', 'qr/irid': '0.0', 'icomp': None, 'tshear': None}, 
 'MAT_ELASTIC': {'mid': 'Steel', 'ro': '8000.000', 'e': '2.0000e+11', 'pr': '0.300000', 'da': '0.0', 'db': '0.0', 'not used': '0.0'}}
```

> *"... Expecting the output somewhat like this Worked ['Steel', '8000.000', '2.0000e+11', ' 0.300000'] ..."*

```java
values = list(data['MAT_ELASTIC'].values())
```

Output

```
['Steel', '8000.000', '2.0000e+11', '0.300000', '0.0', '0.0', '0.0']
```

Comment: Main output here is this.
Steel = 8000.000
Thank you for your additional explanation.